# How to scan specific area using google ml kit for flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, machine-learning, ocr, text-extraction

I'm trying to make a flutter app that can recognize a specific area in a invoice and extract the purchased items with total amount, i want to know how to make google ml kit package scan a specific block and ignore the invoice header like restaurant name and other information, is it possible ?

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: did you find the way?

Comment: @HarinKaklotar unfortunately, No ... if you have any answer please help

Comment: well, I am looking for a solution but also checking other options like using any service which provides ocr service. I'll provide some links so you can also check out that alternate option.